# Tab/focus behavior for radio buttons affected by ng-model in IE11

Tags: angularjs, radio-button, internet-explorer-11

Adding ng-model to a radio button set seems to alter which input gets focused when tabbing. Tested with IE11 (11.842.10586.0), and Angular 1.6.3 (though it occurs in earlier versions of Angular as well).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="formCtrl">
  <form>
    <input type="text" ng-model="firstname">
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" value="1" name="radioExample" checked> 
    <input type="radio" value="2" name="radioExample"> 
    <input type="radio" value="3" name="radioExample">
    <br/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="firstname">

  </form>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('formCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstname = "";
    $scope.radioValue = "1";
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/nwo7sljK4NIEr66T6q7w

This shows the normal behavior. If a radio button is selected, tabbing to the radio button group focuses on the selected radio button. If no radio button selected, tabbing forward focuses on the first element, tabbing back focuses on the last one.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="formCtrl">
  <form>
    <input type="text" ng-model="firstname">
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" value="1" ng-model="radioValue" name="radioExample"> 
    <input type="radio" value="2" ng-model="radioValue" name="radioExample"> 
    <input type="radio" value="3" ng-model="radioValue" name="radioExample">
    <br/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="firstname">

  </form>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('formCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstname = "";
    $scope.radioValue = "1";
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/vMlG7RUg2Kd0sZLmr0lb

This shows the modified behavior when ng-model is added. Regardless of whether a radio button is selected or not, tabbing forward focuses on the first element, tabbing back focuses on the last one. This behavior persists even after a different radio button is selected manually.

I've tried using various combinations of checked/ng-checked, delaying model initialization with $timeout, and using `<fieldset>`.

What is causing this and more importantly is there a way I can make the second scenario behave like the first one (focusing on the selected radio button when tabbing)?

Answer (score 0):

I forked your "modified behavior" example on plnkr and added the `checked` attribute to the first radio button. Tabbing then behaves exactly as it does in your "normal behavior" example.

```
<input type="radio" value="1" ng-model="radioValue" name="radioExample" checked> 
<input type="radio" value="2" ng-model="radioValue" name="radioExample"> 
<input type="radio" value="3" ng-model="radioValue" name="radioExample">
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/gbZFgKJbJyEBdgB9jXho?p=preview

To reconcile any differences between the model and the 'checked' attribute you could add/remove the attribute when the model value changes.

Comment: Tried this out just now, it's not working for me (IE 11, version 11.842.10586.0, update version 11.0.40)

Answer (score 0):

Try with ng-value. `$scope.radioValue = "1";` data type is string change to `$scope.radioValue = 1;`

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('formCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstname = "";
    $scope.radioValue = 1;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="formCtrl">
  <form>
    <input type="text" ng-model="firstname">
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" data-ng-model="radioValue" data-ng-value="1" name="radioExample"> 
    <input type="radio" data-ng-model="radioValue" data-ng-value="2" name="radioExample"> 
    <input type="radio" data-ng-model="radioValue" data-ng-value="3" name="radioExample">
    <br/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="firstname">
    
  </form>
</div>
</body>
```